# How many minium RAM memory requirement for build android ROM on device run ubuntu 64 OS

Tags: android

I want build a ROM version by myself. But I'm not sure if laptop with 4GB RAM memory is enough for development. Anybody help me?

P/s: Laptop is running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Comment: 1 GB RAM and 2 GB ROM for android simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to read the minimum requirements mentioned by Google.

Link: [AOSP Minimum Requirements](http://source.android.com/source/requirements.html)

As an additional note, if you are keeping swap space, make sure it is half the size of your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

16GB is recommended if you are building in a virtual machine on top of windows. I increased the swap partition on 6GB  physical building initially.

I've now built omnirom marshmallow for nexus 10 with Ubuntu 14 natively installed, 16GB of ram. During the build it didn't go much above 6GB RAM use.

You'll find CPU gets max'd out first, at least on my dual core i5 (2.5-3Ghz)

I have read about building Android on ubuntu server, that may have slightly lower RAM requirements.